# windows-motion-controls, a-frame hands controllers for WMR on Edge not appearing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, aframe, webvr

```
<a-entity windows-motion-controls="hand: left"></a-entity>
<a-entity windows-motion-controls="hand: right"></a-entity>
```

I´m trying to use WMR controllers on a-frame but it is not appearing. I´m using Edge browser for develop, this browser supports WebVR.

Comment: Can you share link to reproduce? If you run `navigator.getGamepads()` on console, do you get a list of gamepads? If you do, what's the id, e.g: `navigator.getGamepads()[0].id`

Comment: The problem was the dependecies, it seems that when I dose npm install wiht my version of angular cli had errors, I created a new angular project and it works. Alsou I put a-frame version to 0.8.0

Comment: You should be using 0.9.0

Comment: Ok, I will try with 0.9.0 and I tell you.